# Collaborative filtering for Movie data using number of views & rating in python

Tags: python, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I read about Collaborative filtering for Movie dataset which considers user, item(movie) & rating.

But I want to include number of views as well while recommending the movie. So I have 2 matrices - first (user,movie,rating) and second ( user, movie and number of view). Can anyone explain me how to use both matrices for recommendation?

I liked & referred http://www.salemmarafi.com/code/collaborative-filtering-with-python/ to understand memory based Collaborative filtering.